# How to pick bootstrap datepicker value and post it with form in calendar view with multiple dates

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I've a problem with bootstrap datepicker...

I want a calendar on my html page in which I can select multiple dates and POST all the dates with form.

I have tried bootstrap datepicker. My code is as follows

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  multidate:true,
  format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
  clearBtn: true,
  todayHighlight: true
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

 <div class="datepicker"></div>
```

So what I do by that selected date will post with the form

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getDates` method.
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#getdates

Please see this example https://codepen.io/D-Heap/pen/zPrJyw

In the demo the button collects the selected data and outputs the values to the console. You can use them in an Ajax request to POST them.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

I'd recommend using an ID (unique) for your datepicker element to prevent clashes.

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: @GyandeepSharma - You can format the dates while processing the POST variable. Please consider accepting my answer if that worked for you.

Comment: Great - Thanks :)

Comment: Hay can you help in once again...?

Comment: @GyandeepSharma - What's that about?